# Cannot read property '_handleNewFile' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I've just implemented the example from tutorial page and the normal upload works just fine but I also wan't to make use of the camera on mobile devices, so I've added the code from this [fineuploader blog post](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/05/09/upload-directly-via-a-camera-on-mobile-devices/).

Now, if I click the Camera button the file selection dialog appears or the camera app opens, but that's it. I'm only getting this message in my Javascript debug console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_handleNewFile' of undefined"

Here's my client code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="resources/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="resources/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
      ...default-template...
    </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
  var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
     element: document.getElementById("myFineUploader"),
     camera: {
        ios: true
      },
    debug: true,
    request: {
                 endpoint: 'upload/receiver/'
             }
   });
   
    qq(document.getElementById("cameraButton")).attach("change", function() {
      uploader.addFiles(this);
    });
 });
 </script>
    <title>Fine Uploader default UI</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="cameraButtonContainer" class="qq-upload-button" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; direction: ltr;">
   <div>Camera</div>
   <input id="cameraButton" type="file" name="camera" accept="image/*;capture=camera" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 118px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0;">
 </div>
 <div id="myFineUploader"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that the default example button also make use of the camera on mobile devices, so there is no use of the camera button for me.

**Edit:**
Chrome on IOS 8 won't give the camera option
The Standard browser on Android 4.2.2 opens camera but taken pictures won't be uploaded